# How do I get a set of 3 tiles' position depend on direction of origin

Tags: c#, if-statement, vector, geometry, tile

I have a character which can do an attack on grid that always covers 3 tiles and those tiles' position should depend on the position of the character. I want to know if there is a easier/non-repetitive way of doing this code(I am aware of switch statements but that is not what I am worried about)

```
Vector3Int fromPoint = Vector3Int.zero;
        Vector3Int direction = Vector3Int.RoundToInt(Vector3.Normalize(atPoint - fromPoint));

        retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint);

        if (direction == Vector3Int.up)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.left);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.right);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.up + Vector3Int.right)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.left);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.down);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.right)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.up);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.down);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.right + Vector3Int.down)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.left);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.up);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.down)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.left);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.right);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.left + Vector3Int.down)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.right);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.up);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.left)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.up);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.down);
        }
        if (direction == Vector3Int.left + Vector3Int.up)
        {
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.right);
            retiacalTiles.Add(atPoint + Vector3Int.down);
        }
```

The code that I have posted here works as intended.(I'll change from Point to be character'Pos later). However the code I have is very large and I feel like there should be a simpler way of doing it. The corner tiles are a bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are 8 conditions, and they can be represented by a table consisting of 8 elements.
So if you can obtain index for the table from `direction` with some easy calculation, code may be able to be more short.

Or, if you calculate the 2 result values from `direction` directly (e.g. rotating the direction 45 degree), code may be more short and simple.